# .htaccess file not working on localhost XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have PHP project on localhost using XAMPP and also .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /locations/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But this is not working and I am only getting Error 404. In httpd.conf file I have uncommented this line:

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
```

I am using Windows 8.1. What can I do to make it work, please?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\myProjectRoot

Comment: Because I wanted to redirect url - when I request localhost/myProjectRoot/locations/  I want to redirect to localhost/myProjectRoot/test.php. It is working well on production server version, but not on localhost because of this .htaccess problem, I guess.

Comment: But I dont have locations folder, I want this : when user type localhost/myProjectRoot/locations/ it will 'redirect' him to localhost/myProjectRoot/test.php. So it will instead request this php file. But I tried also create folder locations and place there this .htaccess but it did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^locations(/.*)?$ test.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: I enabled .htaccess by removing <Files ".ht*">Require all denied</Files> from Apache config file. It works and I am getting error 500. But this .htaccess is still not working as I need to (redirection).

Comment: And also, what should I add, If I need to redirect everything url with every string after "localhost/myProjectRoot/locations/" to test.php. For example localhost/myProjectRoot/locations/123456 will go to localhost/myProjectRoot/test.php

Comment: And also, what should I add, If I need to redirect everything url with every string after "localhost/myProjectRoot/locations/" to test.php. For example localhost/myProjectRoot/locations/123456 will go to localhost/myProjectRoot/test.php

Answer (score 2):

using XAMPP then you will find the file at:

{xampp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf

Search for the following string:

## LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

and uncomment it (remove the ‘#’ sign).
Now search for another string AllowOverride None and replace it by AllowOverride All

Comment: I did it, but unfortunatelly after restarting Apache, nothing changed.